# Jquery dropdown menu off navbar not functioning correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a dropdown bar in jquery:

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".dropbtn").hover(function(){
            $(".dropdown-content").slideDown("fast");
            $(".dropdown-content").show;
        });
        $(".dropdown").mouseout(function(){
            $(".dropdown-content").slideUp("fast");
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">##</a>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">##</a>
        <a href="#">##</a>
      </div>
    </li>
    </ul>
```

When I hover over the dropdown li, the dropdown content slides down, but I can't hover over the content without it sliding up. I know the issue lies in the mouseout function in jquery, but nothing I've tried can fix it.

Comment: instead of `.hover()` maybe try `.mouseenter()`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $(".dropbtn").hover(function () {
        $(".dropdown-content").slideDown("fast");
        $(".dropdown-content").show();
    });

    $(".dropdown-content").hide();

    $(".dropdown").mouseout(function () {
        $(".dropdown-content").mouseout(function () {
            $(".dropdown-content").slideUp("fast");
            $(".dropdown-content").show();
        });

    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: It didn't work for me - does the script assume any css display properties?

Comment: @user7548189 look at my updated answer - that may help